# React Ant Design submenu menu item

Tags: reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I am currently using a submenu with a collection menu items of buildings that provide a certain service. I am wondering if there is a way where when a user clicks on a service (submenu) lets say only 4 buildings that provide the service pops down(menu items) initially and the user can mousescroll to see more buildings that provide that service making sure that only 4 buildings show at one time. The project is done in React using Ant Design. Right now all of the menu items are shown all at once when clicking the submenu causing the contents of the app to be streched down.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround that worked for my liking was making a fixed sider by giving the style properties

```
<Sider
      style={{
        overflow: 'auto',
        height: '100vh',
        position: 'fixed',
        left: 0,
      }}
>
```

https://ant.design/components/layout/#components-layout-demo-fixed-sider